# Plural of "fleece" when referring to fleece jacket

Tags: grammatical-number, nouns, adjectives

Is the word *fleece* when referring to a fleece jacket also the plural form, or is that *fleeces*?

Answer (score 7):

If you write *fleece* to mean "a jacket or other garment made from a soft warm fabric with a texture similar to sheep's wool," then the plural is *fleeces*; if you are asking the plural of *fleece jacket*, that is *fleece jackets*.

As *fleece* is also used when talking of a jacket made of fleece (whatever it is sheep's wool, or the soft warm fabric similar to sheep's wool), there is no need to say *fleece jacket*.

Answer (score 0):

The plural of "fleece jacket" is "fleece jackets".

In English, unlike some other languages, when we make a noun plural we do not modify any associated adjectives. For example, "one hot day", "two hot days", NOT "two hots days".

If you were using "fleece" as a noun, then the plural would be "fleeces". "We used the fleeces from two sheep to make jackets. This was enough for three fleece jackets."